# When following .sh file executed from crontab the value of variable is empty. Although it is working fine from linux prompt

Tags: curl, https

vi Pluse.sh

```
macvar=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}')
curl "https://mywebsite.com/Pulse/Pulse.ClockPulse?ActionID=SaveClockPulse&mac=$macvar"
```

I need help to resolve the issue. At tail when I print query following is showing on tail

```
Update MyDatabase.PulseMasterTable Set pulse=now() Where mac=''
```

Comment: I jest need to capture mac address and want to add it in the url that need to be execute through CURL

Comment: That's what you do already

Comment: will you suggest any modification in my script

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path of each executable, like

```
/usr/bin/grep
```

Etc...

Or put at the top of `crontab -e`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for guidance but not effect